# Why can't I use ref.current.classList in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const ref = useRef()  

ref.current.classList.add('blah-blah')
```

`<div ref={ref} className= 'blah'> </div>`

why can't I add class using classList like we do :

`document.querySelector('.blah').classList.add('blah-blah)`

Comment: Because you call it before assigning the element to it. `querySelector` also doesn't work if an element is not present in the DOM

Comment: Maybe try wrapping `ref.current.classList.add('blah-blah')` in `useEffect(() => ...)`? This should delay the execution until after a render.

Comment: Bad idea anyway because the class will be wiped if the element is rerendered

Comment: The thing is I saw in lot of articals that `ref.current.classList.add('classname') ` . but there is no property of ref.current as 'classList'. 
@Konrad you got it little wrong. Actually my code is long. I don;t want you guys read all those messy code.  
visit this repository and see the code. :
https://github.com/bishalkar10/Blog-Generator/blob/main/src/pages/RichTextEditor.jsx  
I have tailwindcss class `animate-slide-up`  which I wanted when the editor content is empty. 
so I could add a class using `document.querySelector('.animate').classList.add('animate-slide-up)`. 
useState solved